# How to solve the following equation? $\log_3\big(\log_x(\log_416)\big)=-1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$$\log_3\big(\log_x(\log_416)\big)=-1.$$

I am trying to solve this equation for $x$. This is what I have so far:

$$\log_3(\log_x 2)= -1.$$

Okay, now I have this:

log2 = (1/3)logx

How do I isolate x from here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adriano's method is another method, I will continue where you stopped:

$$\log_3(\log_x 2)= -1 \Leftrightarrow \frac13=\log_x(2)$$ by the definition of the logarithm.

Now $x^{1/3}=2 \Leftrightarrow x=2^3=8$, again by the definition of the logarithm.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** There is no multiplication going on anywhere in this equation (just nested logs). Try thinking of the stuff inside the brackets as a single unit and convert to exponential form, working your way from the outside to the inside. If it helps, use substitutions. For example, let $u = \log_x(\log_4 16))$, so that we have:
$$
\log_3 u = -1
$$
Converting to exponential form, we have:
$$
u = 3^{-1} \iff \log_x(\log_4 16) =  \frac{1}{3}
$$
Now repeat.

Comment: +1, however, I believe that first step should be reduction $\log_{4}{16}$ to $2$.

Comment: How does u=3^-1 relate to the rest of the problem though? How do I write out my next step?

Comment: Before, we had three logs. After one step, we were able to reduce it to only two logs. If you repeat what I did, we can peel off another log. Can you see how?

Comment: I understand that, thanks. So, log base x is x^1/3? And then I simply solve from there?

Comment: Here is what I have now... log 2 = 1/3logx. What can I do now?

Comment: how do I iosolate x?

Comment: Note that:
$$
\log_x(2) = \frac{1}{3} \iff x^{1/3} = 2
$$
To get rid of the exponent $1/3$, simply cube both sides.